# Mongoose is not updating the data in database

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I am writing using findOneAndUpdate to update the data in database but it is not updating anything. Please tell what is wrong in my code because while updating by same code in robo 3t, it is working.

Here is my code :

```
require('dotenv').config();
var mongoose = require('mongoose');
const { Client_toBeMerged, main_client_id } = require('./mergeClientsArray')

mongoose.connect(process.env.DB_URL);

var Schema = mongoose.Schema;
var Client_Batch = mongoose.model("Model", new Schema({}), 'client_batch_12_copy');

var filter = { "ID": main_client_id };
var update = {
    $set:{
        "dID": "1",
        "CM": "0"

    }
};

Client_Batch.findOneAndUpdate(filter, update, { new: true }, (err, mainClientData) => {

    if (err) throw err;
    else {

        console.log(mainClientData);
    }

})
```

Please help me out in this.

Thanks

Comment: can you double check that you are using the correct field? `ID` ? Looks correct only. Try running only `findOne` with your filter to see if stuff workds

Comment: Yes, it is correct. ID is a different field. In mongoose it is not working while using MongoClient it is working fine. I have used findOne and updateOne also, it is not working. I have taken Model without creating model, I am passing collection name

Comment: So basically no query is working. Your table name is `Models` right? `, 'client_batch_12_copy'` I think this param is useless. It is not required. But it shouln't be a problem. Maybe check if you are passing the corerct values. Just write the simple `find` query with hardcoded values first